# Program not showing windows which show processing and timing

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I run my project some weeks ago and it was showing me window which is showing timing and processing speed and memory its utilizing but now i am running the same code on same tool but its not showing me that screen. I am tried same code on both versions of visual studio 2010 and 2015 but i am getting that screen.

here is the code

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#include <time.h>
float getticks()
{
    struct timespec ts;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts) < 0)
        return -1.0f;

    return ts.tv_sec + 1e-9f*ts.tv_nsec;
}
#else
#include <windows.h>
float getticks()
{
    static double freq = -1.0;
    LARGE_INTEGER lint;

    if (freq < 0.0)
    {
        if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&lint))
            return -1.0f;

        freq = lint.QuadPart;
    }

    if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&lint))
        return -1.0f;

    return (float)(lint.QuadPart / freq);
}
#endif
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast to `float` like that. `float` is only 4 bytes, it can't handle `QuadPart`. Instead use `unsigned long long` or `long long`

```
LARGE_INTEGER freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

LARGE_INTEGER t1;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);

//sleep for about 1 second
Sleep(1000);

LARGE_INTEGER t2;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

long long diff = t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart;

//print the result with varying accuracy:
cout << "seconds: "      << 1          * diff / freq.QuadPart << endl;
cout << "milliseconds: " << 1000       * diff / freq.QuadPart << endl; 
cout << "microseconds: " << 1000000    * diff / freq.QuadPart << endl;
cout << "nanoseconds: "  << 1000000000 * diff / freq.QuadPart << endl;
```

There is also `GetTickCount64` (it's a random counter with accuracy of about 1 milliseconds), `GetSystemTime` and `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` ... depending on what you are trying to do.